# How to keep remark when update type of a column in liquibase?

Tags: groovy, liquibase

I try to update type of a column using [modifyDataType](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/modify-data-type.html) in a [Groovy DSL](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-groovy-dsl). After I run liquibase update by liquibase-maven-plugin(version is 3.8.9), I found the remark of column disappeared.

here is my code:

```
changeSet(author: "root", id: "20201218-modify-data-type") {
    modifyDataType(columnName: "description", newDataType: "text", tableName: "t_user")

    rollback {
        modifyDataType(columnName: "description", newDataType: "varchar(2000)", tableName: "t_user")
    }
}
```

I can not add param "remark" in modifyDataType(), because `'remarks' is an invalid property for 'modifyDataType' changes`.

Comment: What database platform are you using?  Perhaps it was not imlemented in Liquibase for the platform you are using.  If you think this is a bug, and please log a bug here: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues

Comment: @ronak, It is MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way MySQL implements their `ALTER TABLE MODIFY COLUMN` is as if it drops the old column and adds a new one. This loses not just remarks, but also constraints or primary keys or anything else related to the "old" column.

We've not added all those fields into `modifyDataType` since there is really no end to what we'd have to include in there. Instead, if you modify a datatype on mysql you need to re-set the remarks, primary keys, etc. in separate calls.

There is a warning we output for mysql about losing primary key/constraint info, but we only show it for non-varchar datatypes to keep the number of warnings down. Since it affects things like remarks which can be on varchars, it's probably worth removing that non-varchar part of the check.